# how to write a c program that runs on a mobile phone?

Tags: c, mobile-phones

i wanna write a C program that runs on a mobile phone. Just for learning purpose. i think it's possible. but i dont know where to start with and the libraries that are available for it.

> *i have also planned to write a game that runs on a mobile phone.*

help me to do it. thanks in advance.

Comment: How about [**Objective-C**][1]? ;)


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

Comment: @Jacob: objective c is object oriented isn't it? i wanna use procedural native C language.

Comment: What kind of mobile phone? The APIs you would use differ wildly depending on what the operating system is.

Comment: @Martin: any mobile but not java phones and iPhones. i dont prefer a mobile model. i wanna learn how to write a program that runs on a mobile phone. even if it is a mobile emulator, it's fine for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know a mobile platform where its SDK are reccomending using pure C anymore. Last that I knew of was the old Palm platform.

But you can write C/C++ with QT as GUI library for Maemo, MeeGo and possibly other Nokia devices. QT are object oriented, so its not procedural as you want.

I know of 1 platform where pure C is possible. That's the windows mobile version <6.5 using win32 api. But this is not a thing I personally recommend doing since C#.NET makes it easier to develop applications for that platform.  I also think that pure C combined with XML/CSS using the WebOS PDK is possible but I might be wrong here.

If you have a wish to write for mobile devices using your knowledge in C then i would rather recommend to use languages like C++ and Objective-C where you also can write C and use C libraries.

A list of mobile devices and the programming languages used to develop applications for them:

```
Symbian - C/C++
iOS - Objective-C
Android - Java
Windows Mobile -  C/C++/.NET
WebOS - C/C++
```

Answer (score 2):

How about [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/). It's OS-independent SDK. MoSync applications are written in the C and C++ programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Programming is almost same. Try downloading one of the SDKs and review the documents for any of the platforms you want.

1) iPhone

2) Android

3) Bada (This is Samsung's latest platform)

SDK comes with cross compilers , simulators and IDE to assist you.

Will add more to this.

Answer (score 0):

Java-to-C compiler may work in J2ME case. You can try Clue: http://cluecc.sourceforge.net/